# Intellij idea 13.1 how to check VM option for a running application

Tags: java, spring, web-services, intellij-idea

Hi I am new to Intellij , I am running a spring web services application on tomcat server.

While starting server I pass CONFIG_MODE , like -DCONFIG_MODE=DEV which tell which env it belongs to ( it is internal logic in my application to identify dev , qa ... env)

Somehow I believe VM machine options is passed wrongly. Now I want to check at runtime what are values for my VM parameters passed while starting application. Tried searching google but did not get anything useful , need your help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a sysout for the same ?

System.getenv() or System.getProperty()

Comment: I put it in watch and saw result , used to work in eclipse so was looking for some tool. But it is nice trick which dint strike me at first :)